# Request is still be authenticated but Session["account"] was lost in Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, authentication

I used FormsAuthentication for my website with my own database, in the login function, I use FormsAuthenticate.setAuth() and set Session["account"] with my logged in account variable. Sometime in the layout page, the Request.IsAuthenticated still be true but the Session["account"] was lost, cause me a null reference. I found this in SO, fix Global.asax, but it doesn't always working:

```
protected void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Check if user is authenticated
            HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
            if (authCookie != null)
            {
                FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
                if (!authTicket.Expired)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (Session["account"] == null)
                        {
                            //Session is null, redirect to login page
                            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
            }
        }
```

I need a better solution

Comment: For what purpose do you need Session["account"]?

Comment: I want to display username as a link in a corner of layout, so from any page, user can access to the profile page

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment:

```
I want to display username as a link in a corner of layout, so from any page, user can access to the profile page
```

My suggestion is to not use Session for this purpose. Session object should be used with caution and should be avoided if possible. For one, they tend to make web application difficult to work under a load balancer scenario.

You can use `User.Identity.Name` as shown below in your `_Layout.cshtml` or `_LayoutPartial.cshtml`:

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <div class="clear_both">
        <ul class="headernav1">
            <li><span id="spWelcome">Welcome, </span><span id="username">@Html.Raw(User.Identity.Name)</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
   </div>
}
```

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention, I am using my own FormAuthentication :(, so I can't use "User"